# 301 redirect wildcards

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem due to an error of programmation and in Google webmaster I have more than 10000 errors.
The error is in the rss feed of the article:
I have to redirect a lot of this kind of wrong permalink

```
http://www.mysitename.it/00000000/permalink//feed/
```

to this correct structure of permalink

```
http://www.mysitename.it/00000000/permalink/feed/
```

In practice I have to delete one / (slash) before feed

If is possible I need to use the redirect 301 rule instead Mod rewrite because i have some lines of this redirect in my Wordpress htaccess file.
Thanks in advance
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(00000000/permalink)//(feed/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```